# point only a subdomian to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, vercel

I own the example.com domain name. For the moment I connect that to two services.

One for firebase as a A name record for the sudomian business.example.com
Another for AWS as A record and a CNAME record.

This is my namecheap Advanced DNS settings

| Type | Host | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A record | @ | AWS IP |
| CNAME record | api | example.com |
| A record | business | Firebase IP |

For the moment if I visit http://example.com/ it will show me the "Welcome to nginx", So that is clear that since the host is point to @ in the A record, the domian is fully connected to the AWS eC-2
What I want is to ONLY CONNECT api.example.com to AWS and connect full domain to vercel. So that I can use example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in vercel.

How do I do this?

Comment: Change `@` to the vercel IP and change `api` to A record with the AWS IP. I am not clear what they question is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have created an **Elastic IP address** in the Amazon EC2 management console. This is a static IP address that will stay with the instance (and can be moved to other instances).

Then, configure your DNS with an `A`-record that points `api` to the Elastic IP address:

| Type | Host | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A record | @ | Vercel IP address |
| A record | api | Elastic IP address (eg 1.2.3.4) |
| A record | business | Firebase IP |